# How to can I create an array of 10^15 positions?

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I need to create an array of 10^15 positions, based on the amount of positions, I thought it would be necessary to create a long array, however, the index of the array needs to be Int, I tried with BigInteger but it needed to convert the BigInteger into an Int and when doing so, it changed to a negative number, so the array could not be created.

Here's the code:

```
BigInteger num = new  BigInteger("1000000000000000");
    long[] array = new long[num.intValue()];
```

if I print num.intValue() it shows that the number is -1530494976

Comment: Thats bit rotation. num has crossed the size limit for int. You  will have to use BigInt only

Comment: I feel like you need to redesign whatever you are making, if you need an array that large. If you tell us more about what you are trying to make, perhaps we can suggest a way to do it that doesn't require such a monstrous array.

Comment: You'd better call Google.  I'm not sure anyone else has that much storage.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that declaring the array as `long[]` only means that you will store longs inside it, instead of ints, strings or whatever other type/class. It doesn't affect to the array size.

Comment: I see, but the things is that I was given a problem in which I need to create an array with that size, I tried to redesign the algorithm with ArrayList and LinkedList but it's not as efficient as I need it and consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: As I said, explain the problem to us, and maybe we can help you come up with a workable solution.

Comment: A `long` is 64 bits. 64*10^15 bits is **7,11 Petabytes**, or **7275,96 Terabytes**. There is absolutely 0 chance that you have such a big amount of memory. It would take you years just to 0-set the array.

Comment: I found the solution for my problem, I misunderstood the conditions of the given problem, but thank you so much.

Comment: This smells, a lot. Provide the problem please. Otherwise Map<BigInteger, Long>. This way your list will only contain values for numbers for which you actually set a value, and based on time needs that is the only possible way to implement it as people above mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in Java are limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` entries.
If you need more elements, you need to have multiple arrays, each storing some part.
It could look like this:

```
long[][] array = new long[1_000_000][1_000_000_000];

BigInteger num = your-actual-array-index-you-want-access;
int majorIndex = num.longValue() / 1_000_000;
int minorIndex = num.longValue() % 1_000_000;
array[majorIndex][minorIndex] = value;
```

But: you know how much memory this will use? I doubt your machine has that much memory...

Comment: 64 bits long * 10^15 = 6.4*10^16 bits / 8 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024/ 1024 / 1024 = ~7 Petabyte... yeah I doubt it too

Answer (score 1):

Java's stock arrays are limited in size to a maximum of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. There are third-party libraries that try to overcome this limitation (such as
[JLargeArrays](https://github.com/IcmVis/JLargeArrays)), but... you should check closely, if you really want that many fields. Maybe your algorithm is just poorly designed. But I can't tell from your post, of course.